# SQL Server Calculated Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, calculated-columns

I have two columns, both int's, `Wins` and `Losses`. I have a calculated column `WinPercentage` as a `decimal(14,3)`, I want this to be:

```
WinPercentage = (Wins + Losses) / Wins
```

What's the syntax for that?

Comment: I think WinPercentage should probably be 100.0 * Wins / (Wins + Losses).  Make sure you use 100.0 to avoid integer math.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE WinLoss
(
 TeamId int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 Wins int,
 Losses int,
 WinPercentage AS CASE WHEN wins > 0 THEN (Wins + Losses) / Wins ELSE 0 END
)
```

Comment: If i was just putting this into the column properties toolbox, would I just put in everything after the 'AS'

Comment: @Scott .... Yes I believe so.... I have strayed away from using the design tools as I can see more of what is going on when I type it in.  But yes I believe you are right.

Comment: You want to check the wins value, or risk a division by zero error when selecting records - an insert works fine.

Comment: How would I check Wins for 0 and set the column = 0 if this were the case.

Comment: @Scott look at the edited answer.. OMG Ponies edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

To create a calculated column into the existed table, then use "ALTER TABLE".

The formula for win percentage is
Win Percentage = (Wins / (Wins + Losses)) * 100

When the total of wins and losses is 0, the NULLIF function is utilized to prevent division by zero problems.

```
    ALTER TABLE [Win Loss Percentage]
    ADD WinPercentage AS (CONVERT(decimal(5, 2), (Wins * 100.0 / NULLIF((Wins + Losses), 0)))) PERSISTED;
```

Hope! it's helpful.