# How do I use CASE in SQL for my example?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have 3 columns of data: Age, Gender, Points.
Age is age, gender is either M or F, and Points range from 1-100.

How do I make a new column so that if gender is M you add 5 points to whatever is in the Points column, and if gender is F you subtract 3 points from whatever is in the Points column?

I think I'm going to need CASE.  I've added a new column called PointsRevised by using ALTER TABLE, then add.

Now, I want to populate this new PointsRevised column with new values depending if gender is M or F.

```
UPDATE [Example].[dbo].[example]
SET POINTSREVISED
CASE 
WHEN Gender = 'M' Then PointsRevised = Points + 5  
WHEN Gender = 'F' Then PointsRevised = Points - 3
END
```

I'm clearly doing something wrong.

Comment: do you want to do it just this once, and never again, or is this something that you want to do regularly?

Comment: I do not know much about MS SQL, but it seems like you are trying to do something which belongs in a view to an actual data table.  The only way to accomplish this would be with some very interesting feature of MS SQL allowing for a column to have a computed value which essentially acts like a view.

Comment: @digitalfrenchfry once, and never again. thanks.  out of curiosity, from a high-level overview, what changes if I choose to it regularly?

Comment: @phan for example, if its something you wanted it to happen every day, you can create a stored procedure that loops itself every 24 hours.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will work:

```
UPDATE [Example].[dbo].[example]
SET POINTSREVISED =
  CASE 
  WHEN Gender = 'M' THEN Points + 5  
  WHEN Gender = 'F' THEN Points - 3
  END
```

Simpler:

```
UPDATE [Example].[dbo].[example]
SET POINTSREVISED =
  CASE Gender
  WHEN 'M' THEN Points + 5  
  WHEN 'F' THEN Points - 3
  END
```

If the only valid values for Gender is 'M' and 'F' (and it can't be NULL), you could replace the above `WHEN 'F' THEN` with simply `ELSE`.

Depending on your requirements, a [computed column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4093014/sql-server-calculated-column) may work better.

Comment: Regarding the simpler expression, what if Gender is null?