# Update column using case expression sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to set column value only if it is not blank.

Here is sample

```
Declare @Temp Varchar(20)

Update Logins
Set ColValue = 
Case When @Temp <> '' Then @Temp Else /* Dont SET Value */ End
Where Code=1
```

What to write in `Else` Part ?

I have multiple columns to update and want to apply condition in only single column

DB : SQL SERVER 2008

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14762374/how-do-i-use-case-in-sql-for-my-example  may this help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set the updated column as below:

```
Declare @Temp Varchar(20)

Update Logins
Set ColValue = Case When @Temp <> '' Then @Temp 
                    Else ColValue 
               End
Where Code=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check your variable in WHERE to not update at all when it's blank

```
Declare @Temp Varchar(20)

Update Logins
Set ColValue = @Temp
Where Code=1 AND @Temp <> ''
```

Comment: I have multiple columns to update and want to apply condition in only single column

Comment: @SagarDumbre Well, in that case, use other solution with `ELSE ColValue` in CASE :)